# Any way to Invoke Matlab to compute picture similarity?

Tags: matlab, neural-network

We are working on our project which involves implementing Neural Network to detect Phishing

Currently , we are planning to use the URL and a Screenshot of the website opened in the Browser and pass it as a string & JPEG file to a program . We want this program to invoke Matlab and search

a) similar image in our Whitelisted Website image databases .
b) Similar URL in our Blacklisted Website databases obtained in an XML file

we will compute a score based on these evaluations and assign a phishing rating to the website .

We are in initial stages , so just wanted to know if this is at all feasible ? 
Help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is quite unusual, but after reading it twice I think your main question is:

> Can I do the mentioned things in Matlab?

In this case the answer is definately *yes*.

For example, Matlab can certainly:

1. Compare images (You may want to get the image processing toolbox for advanced things)
2. Identify patterns in a string
3. Connect to a database/read in files
4. Be called from other programs
5. Train a neural network

Just make sure you have access to the right toolboxes/resources, these may include:

Image processing toolbox, neural network toolbox, compiler

Comment: What exactly are these toolboxes ? Extra software or extensions ?? Where can i get the toolboxes ??  

I have some toolboxes , but not the ones mentioned :(

Comment: @Ameya05 They are like expansion packs. You can probably get them the same way you got Matlab itself.