# Neural Network for Phishing detection , features to be extracted from URL and contents to pass as input

Tags: matlab, neural-network

This is in continuation with my [Previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939950/any-way-to-invoke-matlab-to-compute-picture-similarity)

We successfully extracted the **URL** and **contents** from a website which we are supposed to check for phish .

Now we have a database of **whitelist** and **blacklisted** websites as well as their contents . Can we train a NN with the help of these inputs ??

If not , what can be the suggested Features we can extract from a URL and the Contents of a website to train a NN and then later on check a website for phish using these NN ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think a neural net would be appropriate for this. You're going to have a hard time figuring out how to classify the inputs.

Instead, a Bayesian classifier would be more appropriate. Split your URL and contents into tokens and work from there. This is essentially the basis behind [Bayesian spam filtering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_spam_filtering).